# How are object attributes being accessed?

Tags: python

Can some help me with the `current_root.data.tolist() == goal_node.tolist():`
in the following code? Like I know it's comparing the goal_node and current_root by making them into a list first. But what exactly is `.data` doing?

Also, in `current_root = node_q.pop(0)` node_q is a list of object. So what exactly is being "popped" by the pop function?

```
import numpy as np  # Used to store the digits in an array
import os  # Used to delete the file created by previous running of the program


class Node:
        def __init__(self, node_no, data, parent, act, cost):
            self.data = data
            self.parent = parent
            self.act = act
            self.node_no = node_no
            self.cost = cost

def exploring_nodes(node):
    print("Exploring Nodes")
    actions = ["down", "up", "left", "right"]
    goal_node = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 0]])
    node_q = [node]
    final_nodes = []
    visited = []
    final_nodes.append(node_q[0].data.tolist())  # Only writing data of nodes in seen
    node_counter = 0  # To define a unique ID to all the nodes formed
    while node_q:
        current_root = node_q.pop(0)  # Pop the element 0 from the list
        if current_root.data.tolist() == goal_node.tolist():
            print("Goal reached")
            return current_root, final_nodes, visited

k = np.array([[4, 1, 3], [2, 5, 6], [7, 8, 0]])
root = Node(0, k, None, None, 0)
exploring_nodes(root)
```

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.data.html

Comment: "But what exactly is .data doing?" `.data` returns a memoryview object of the underlying buffer. It is *totally* pointless here, and isn't doing anything usefull. You also don't have to turn `numpy.ndarray` objects into lists to compare them.

Comment: How can I do it without turning them into objects?

Comment: What? They *are objects*, I don't understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

About the comparison:
Both variables that are being compared are numpy arrays therefore they are an instance of a class and not just a list. So .data is used to get to the actual values of the numpy array. .toList() just converts them both to a list so they are easily compared to see if they are the same

About the popping:
In this case it will remove index 0 of the list and return it. When the loop goes round the first time it gets the node value back as that is what is orginally in the list

Comment: "Both variables that are being compared are numpy arrays therefore they are an instance of a class and not just a list" lists are instances of a class too

Comment: They are however in python you don't have to say list.data to access the values of a list because it is a language defined class and it is also a type that is my point

Comment: Um, you don't have to do that with numpy.ndarray objects either, and none of that has anything to do with being a built-in. Classes and types are *synonymous*

Comment: It has a lot to do with it being built in because if I defined a new class called it list and it had the same functions and everything as a list. I couldn't use initialise it and other stuff in the same manner as a list.

Comment: um, what do you mean exactly? Yeah, you can't use literal notation which is baked into the language syntax, but how is that relevant to anything?

Comment: Note, `.data` doesn't give you the values of a `numpy` array, whatever you mean by that, it returns a memoryview object over the underlying buffer. It's totally pointless in this case, and the code just looks like it is written by someone unfamiliar with numpy.

Answer (score 0):

> Like I know it's comparing the goal_node and current_root by making them into a list first. But what exactly is .data doing?

Because `current_root` is an object, it cannot not directly store other things,  that's why the elements are stored in a property called `data`.

> Also, in current_root = node_q.pop(0) node_q is a list of object. So what exactly is being "popped" by the pop function?

As written in the code:

```py
current_root = node_q.pop(0)  # Pop the element 0 from the list
```

Because `node_q` is a list, `node_q.pop(0)` removes (pop) the element at the position 0. In your case, it removes the object that is at the index 0.

Comment: But doesn't `node_q` has only one element in the list? If it gets popped the while loop exists since `node_q` will be empty

Comment: Yes, you are right. In that case it seems there will be only one iteration. Maybe the person wrote it like that because he did not want to use a for loop, I don't know